# Toggling CSS3 animation

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to make a toggle sidebar which animates.

When I try to hide the sidebar with CSS3 Transition property by adding a hidebar class, it works perfectly. But It's a toggle, and when I show it again, there is no transition. The menu just snaps out.

```
#page-content.hidebar   {
transition: margin 0.3s ease;
margin-left: 0;
}
```

Can anyone suggest how can I have the transition property when I toggle the sidebar to visibility as well?

I am attaching a fiddle as an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/dxYCm/1/

Comment: ANSWER: CSS specificity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to do several things:

- since all rules have been applied using id selectors in css, your class selector had no effect, as in css specificity it had low points to override previous rules specified under id. So you need to add `!important`. **http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/** Learn more there...
- You needed to put `white-space:nowrap;` as text/content of first div would curl up as div would get small.

Check it Out>>>

**http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/dxYCm/5/**

Comment: I totally forgot about the white-space: no-wrap. Now the sidebar toggles in and out very smoothly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `hide` class at all, jQuery has awesome built in features that do the same thing like [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [`.slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)!

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dxYCm/3/) of `.toggle`

```
$("a#menu-trigger").click(function () {
    $("#page-sidebar").toggle("fast");
    $("#page-content").toggleClass("hidebar");
});
```

Also, you want to apply the transition to `#page-content`, not `#page-content.hidebar` so it transitions both expanding and contracting

If you do still want to do it with using a `.hide` class not changing the jQuery or the HTML, you can do it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/dxYCm/4/), by toggling the width and height

Relevant CSS for that:

```
.hide {height:0px; width:0px; color:transparent;}
#page-sidebar   {width: 230px; float:left; transition: all 0.3s ease;}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I am new to the transition property. I applied the transition to `#page-content` with Umer's white-space modification and now the sidebar toggles in and out smoothly.